# How to get function in other class in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to get function in other class (in state class), my code on first class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  Search({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
   _title(){
      return 'Lorem Ipsum Title';
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //...
   }
}
```

then in second class :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'partials/search.dart';

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  Second({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // I need import functions here, so I can use it on Scaffold

    new Search();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          titleSpacing: 15,
          title: _title() // like this
        ),
      ...
  }
}
```

but I got error when call the function, help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could either use a **Static** method or just call the method on an instance of class **Search**, and in both ways by convention **_** is only used to name local methods/vars which only could be used by the wrapping class.

> Example 1

```
    class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
      String title(){
      return 'Lorem Ipsum Title';
     }

    class Second extends StatelessWidget {
    ...
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Search _search = Search();
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              titleSpacing: 15,
            title: _search.title() // like this
                        ),
       //...
      )} 
  }
```

> Example 2

```
class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
   Static String title(){
      return 'Lorem Ipsum Title';
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //...
   }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
//...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          titleSpacing: 15,
          title: Search.title() // like this
        ),
     // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dart you can use `functions` are `Object` to and can be send like a parameter so you can send it by the constructor and use it in your second class.

[Here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions) its the documentation about what i say.

But you have cant use (_) because that will hide the methods (it's gonna become private) so first need to remove that so you can be able to use it that way.

Now you need to define, *that method will be use in other places* so you can create a class and import it to where ever you are gonna use it.

Conclusion:
Need to know first what you are gonna do with that method and then implemented the better way you can.